# nightwatch Error: Cannot find module 'e2e/step_definitions/analysis.js'

Tags: gulp, cucumber, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing, angular-test

We have an angular 4 project and we're trying to add some e2e tests using gulp, nightwatch and cucumber but every time we run the tests the following error happens:

```
$ gulp e2e-tests
[11:15:12] Using gulpfile ~project/path/gulpfile.js
[11:15:12] Starting 'e2e-tests'...
[11:15:12] Starting 'e2e-scenarios'...
[11:15:12] log file
[11:15:12] Starting nightwatch...
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  18742

There was an error while starting the test runner:

Error: Cannot find module 'e2e/step_definitions/xxxx.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /project/path/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js:163:16
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Below is the configuration we have:

nightwatch.conf

```
var seleniumServer = require('selenium-server');
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

require('nightwatch-cucumber')({
  cucumberArgs: ['--require', 'e2e/step_definitions', '--format', 'json:reports/cucumber.json', 'e2e/features']
});

module.exports = {
    // Loads nightwatch-cucumber configuration into main nightwatch.js conf
    custom_commands_path: '',
    custom_assertions_path: '',
    page_objects_path: '',
    live_output: false,
    disable_colors: false,


    // Sets configuration for Selenium Server
    selenium: {
        start_process: true,
        server_path: seleniumServer.path,
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 4444,
        cli_args : {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver" : chromedriver.path
          }
    },

// Sets config options for different testing environments defined by the user
test_settings: {
    default: {
        launch_url: '',
        selenium_port: 4444,
        selenium_host: '127.0.0.1',
        silent: true,
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            acceptSslCerts: true
        },
        'screenshots': {
            enabled: true,
            on_error: true,
            on_failure: true,
            path: '/screenshots'
        }
    },
    chrome: {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            acceptSslCerts: true
        }
    }
}
};
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.104",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nightwatch = require('gulp-nightwatch');
var reporter = require('gulp-protractor-cucumber-html-report');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('default', function() {
 return console.log('Starting gulp tasks…');
});

gulp.task('login', function() {
 return gulp.src('')
   .pipe(nightwatch({
     configFile: 'nightwatch.conf.js'
   }))
});

//E2E tasks
gulp.task('e2e-scenarios', [], function e2e() {
  let tags = '';
  let skipTags = '';
  let tagIndex = process.argv.indexOf("--tag");
  let skipTagIndex = process.argv.indexOf("--skiptags");
  if (tagIndex > -1) {
    tags = process.argv[tagIndex + 1];
    tags = '--tag ' + tags;
  }
  if (skipTagIndex > -1) {
    skipTags = process.argv[skipTagIndex + 1];
    skipTags = '--skiptags ' + skipTags;
  }

  return gulp.src('')
    .pipe(nightwatch({
      configFile: 'nightwatch.conf.js',
      cliArgs: [tags, skipTags]
    }));
});

gulp.task('e2e-report', function () {
  return gulp.src('./reports/cucumber.json')
    .pipe(reporter({
      dest: 'reports/'
    }));
});

gulp.task('e2e-tests', function (done) {
  runSequence('e2e-scenarios', 'e2e-report', function () {
    done();
  });
});
```

And this is the project Structure

Project
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHHV2.jpg)

Please help me to find out what is causing this issue.

Comment: Is there a place where you are using `require('e2e/step_definitions/xxxx.js')`? I don't see that anymore in the stuff you posted? Also, why are you using nightwatch instead of protractor?

Comment: Yes, we added it in nightwatch.conf. We are using nigthwatch because someone in the team already used it.